# Is highmem relevant in 64 bit Linux? If not, why?

Tags: linux, 64bit

Somewhere on the web, I read that 64bit Linux kernels do not have a highmem issue. I did not find any explanation/detail as to how/why it is not an issue. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 5):

From  `Documentation/vm/highmem.txt`:

> **High memory (highmem) is used when the size of physical memory approaches or
>   exceeds the maximum size of virtual memory.**  At that point it becomes
>   impossible for the kernel to keep all of the available physical memory mapped
>   at all times.  This means the kernel needs to start using temporary mappings of
>   the pieces of physical memory that it wants to access.

For 32bit systems, the maximum size of virtual memory is 2<sup>32</sup> i.e. 4Gb. That limit is reached pretty fast nowadays, so highmem is a big concern for 32bit systems with a lot of RAM.

For 64bit systems, the theoretical maximum virtual memory size is 2<sup>64</sup>, i.e. 18446744073709551616 bytes (16.8 *million terabytes*). That is way beyond what you can stuff into a computer today. So highmem is not an issue on 64bit systems.