# What's the difference between kmap and page_address in x64 system?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

`kmap()` allows you to map a page to some address that functions in kernel or modules can access. While `page_address()` also allows you to retrieve the address to access the page.

It says that `kmap()` is used to deal with highmem issue, but as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32083/is-highmem-relevant-in-64-bit-linux-if-not-why) question explained, highmem is no longer an issue in x64 system.

I've tried that if you get a page struct `*p` from a process (i.e. a userspace page), using `kmap(p)` and `page_address(p)` does nearly same thing.

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

On x86-64, there is no practical difference; when given a non-highmem page, [`kmap` delegates to `page_address`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.9/source/include/linux/highmem-internal.h#L45):

```c
    if (!PageHighMem(page))
        addr = page_address(page);
```

The two functions do however serve two different purposes: `page_address` returns the page’s address, *if it has one*; `kmap` ensures that the page is mapped before returning its address, and should be balanced with a call to `kunmap`.